# SQL Server 2008 dynamic  query doubt

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the purpose of system table table master..spt_values and what are the meanings of its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-mea)
>   [Why (and how) to split column using master..spt_values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273978/why-and-how-to-split-column-using-master-spt-values)

I have some dynamic SQL, I have this lines that will be executed, whats the meaning of `spt_values, and the type='P'`

```
declare @Sql nvarchar(max)
select @Sql = ISNULL(@sql + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(RIGHT(number,10))
    from master..spt_values 
    where type='P' and number between 1 and (select COUNT(*) From tableName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spt_values` is a table in the `master` database. As such, it's meant for internal SQL Server use only, and **is undocumented** to the public.

Basically the code you've got is a quick way to get your hands on a resultset of numbers.

Comment: and what about the `type='P'`

Comment: I was searching and it says is for Projection, but what does it mean?