# Get the value of a column replacing the comma separator

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I get each value of a column that has a comma separator in her value ?

Example:

```
ID   ColumnUnified
1    12,34,56,78
2    80,99,70,56
```

What I want is a query to get the number without comma. If possible, in collumns.

```
12    34     56    78
```

Comment: Always will be 4 values separated by comma, for field?

Comment: Your database structure is violationg the first normalisation rule. You are better off redesigning your DB.

Comment: There is a similar question here.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql

Comment: @ElVieejo not always, can be 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for any number of values http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10844/splitting-delimited-data-to-columns-set-based-approach.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution Madhivanan's link refers to is very creative, but I had a slight problem with it on SQL Server 2012 related to the name of one of the columns (Start). I've modified the code in his answer to use `StartPos` instead of `Start` for the column name.

I was not familiar with the system procedure `spt_values`, but I found a very informative [description of the procedure here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273978/why-and-how-to-split-column-using-master-spt-values) for those who are interested in exactly how this solution works.

Finally, here's the (slightly) revised code from Madhivana's answer:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(id int, data varchar(100))

INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1,'This,is,a,test,string')
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (2,'See,if,it,can,be,split,into,many,columns')

DECLARE @pivot varchar(8000)
DECLARE @select varchar(8000)

SELECT  @pivot = COALESCE(@pivot + ',', '') + '[col'
        + CAST(number + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ']'
FROM    master..spt_values
WHERE   type = 'p'
        AND number <= ( SELECT  MAX(LEN(data) - LEN(REPLACE(data, ',', '')))
                        FROM    #test
                      )

SELECT  @select = '
    select p.*
    from (
    select
    id,substring(data, StartPos+2, endPos-StartPos-2) as token,
    ''col''+cast(row_number() over(partition by id order by StartPos) as varchar(10)) as n
    from (
    select
    id, data, n as StartPos, charindex('','',data,n+2) endPos
    from (select number as n from master..spt_values where type=''p'') num
    cross join
    (
    select
    id, '','' + data +'','' as data
    from
    #test
    ) m
    where n < len(data)-1
    and substring(data,n+1,1) = '','') as data
    ) pvt
    Pivot ( max(token)for n in (' + @pivot + '))p'

EXEC(@select)

DROP TABLE #test
```