# Fastest way to generate and populate a table with a set of (x,y) values

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to insert 100,000,000 simple coordinate based records into a table. Is there a faster way to make this happen than the t-sql command below

```
declare @x int
declare @y int
set @x = 0
set @y = 0

begin tran
while @x < 10000
begin
    while @y < 10000
    begin
        insert into world (x,y) VALUES (@x,@y)
        set @y = @y + 1
    end
    set @y = 0
    set @x = @x + 1
end
commit tran
```

Comment: DO you have those coordinates available in an external file? You could bulkload that into a staging table....

Comment: I do not, but I suspect creating a file would take as long as the query above. Time to experiment.

Comment: Rather than 100,000,000 individual INSERTs, you probably would be better off with either INSERT INTO SELECT syntax or SELECT INTO syntax.  Of those, I would guess SELECT INTO might perform better.  See [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLSelectInsert.aspx), for example.

Comment: I see you have and accepted answer.  But another option might be insert 10000 rows into a #temp and do a cross join.

Comment: I have to say that the answer by @StingyJack appears to be a faster solution than mine, even when inserting the final result into a permanent table rather than #values. If this is something you do regularly, you may want to experiment a little bit with that.

Comment: I'm going to, yours worked fine, it was a one off thing. I'm still interested in his solution, will get some time this weekend for my curiosity run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work if 100 mill rows isn't too big a mouthful for the server to do in one piece - it obviously depends on the size and speed of your log-file.

```
WITH counter AS 
(SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (ORDER BY a.[object_id], a.name, b.[object_id]) AS rownum 
   FROM sys.columns a, sys.columns b) 
INSERT INTO World (x,y) 
SELECT a.rownum, b.rownum 
  FROM counter a, counter b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have Number table, please use your own Number table. Otherwise, you can use spt_values like below.

```
WITH base_num AS
(SELECT number FROM master..spt_values WHERE type = 'P' AND number < 100)
, num AS 
(SELECT b1.number * 100 + b2.number AS number
 FROM base_num b1
 CROSS JOIN base_num b2
) 
INSERT INTO world (x,y)
SELECT n1.number AS x, n2.number AS y 
FROM num n1
CROSS JOIN num n2
```

Comment: spt_values is undocumented and could give unexpected results. In this case it may not produce enough to generate the records required.

Comment: @StingyJack, as I mentioned in my answer, if OP have own number table, then should use it. Also, could you please give a example that "spt_values could give unexpected results". I would really interest to know it.

Comment: Its considered an "internal" and thus not documented. If there is no documentation, then you are inferring the behavior and it could do something unexpected. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4280038/16391

Comment: @StingyJack, if I read the link correctly, the answer says "Why we should use spr_values", not opposite.

Comment: The title of the link is unimportant. The point was that you are recommending an undocumented method that may produce unexpected or non-guarantee-able results, and that only lists about 2500 records each unless you do something else. 2500 elements squared is only going to get about 6MM rows, and OP needs 100MM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a numbers table

```
 SELECT TOP 10000 -- use a smaller value for testing, this will take a bit
        IDENTITY(INT,1,1) as N
   INTO #Numbers
   FROM Master.dbo.SysColumns sc1,
        Master.dbo.SysColumns sc2
```

Then something like

```
SELECT
    n1.N as 'N1'
    , n2.N as 'N2'
INTO #values
FROM #Numbers n1
    CROSS JOIN #Numbers n2


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #values
```

To get the cartesian of the sets, provided you can use simplified coordinate values.

Comment: It took about 12 seconds to generate a million numbers. I only have a shared VM SQL Server to use, so I dont dare try 100MM.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a numbers table, you can simulate one with a CTE:

```
with cte as
(select 1 i union all select i+1 i from cte where i < 10000)
INSERT into World (x,y) 
SELECT x.i, y.i 
from cte x cross join cte y
option (maxrecursion 0)
```