# calculate 3 working days before in stored proc using Holidays lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

I have a tricky issue I am struggling with on a mental level.

In our db we have a table showing the UK Holidays for the next few years, and a stored function returns a recordset to my front end.

I have a flag in my recordset called 'deletable' which allows the frontend to decide if a context menu can be shown in the data grid, thus allowing that record to be deleted.

Currently the test (in my stored proc) just checks if the date column has a date from three days ago or more.

```
case when DATEDIFF(d,a.[date],GETDATE()) > 3 then 1 else 0 end as [deletable]
```

how can I modify that to find the previous working date by checking weekends and the Holidays table 'Holiday' column (which is a Datetime) and see if the [date] column in my recordset row is 3 working days before, taking into account Holidays from the Holidays table and weekends?

so if the [date] column is 23th May, and todays's date is 28th May, then that column returns 0, as the 27th was a bank holiday, whereas the next day it would return 1 because there would be more than 3 working days difference.

Is there an elegent way to do that?

thanks
Philip

Comment: Does your table just have holidays, or does it have all days with holidays flagged?

Comment: it has just Holidays dates as datetime, one per holiday for several years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I'm totally refactoring this.

```
declare
    @DeletablePeriodStart datetime,
    @BusinessDays int

set @DeletablePeriodStart = dateadd(d,0,datediff(d,0,getdate()))
set @BusinessDays = 0

while @BusinessDays < 3
begin
    set @DeletablePeriodStart = dateadd(d,-1,@DeletablePeriodStart)
    if datepart(dw,@DeletablePeriodStart) not in (1,7) and
        not exists (select * from HolidayTable where Holiday = @DeletablePeriodStart)
    begin
        set @BusinessDays = @BusinessDays + 1
    end
end
```

This time it doesn't make any assumptions. It runs a quick loop checking whether each day is a valid business day and doesn't stop till it counts three of them. Then later just check whether `a.[date] >= @DeletablePeriodStart`

Comment: OP wants to take into account weekends too.

Comment: Easy enough to expand this approach to include weekends. I'll update.

Comment: @JC. thanks, how would I modify that to take into account weekends? Basically, if the date in the table row is more than 3 working days ago (taking into account holidays from the Holidays table and weekends) then this column in my dataset should be 1, else 0 as [deleteble]

Comment: I added some code that basically increments `@MaxAge` if the current date is Monday or Tuesday. You can adjust as necessary for your locale. Just check the `@@DateFirst` variable. If `@@DateFirst` is 1 (Monday) for your locale then `datepart(dw,GetDate())` will return 1 for a Monday.

Comment: @JC. it's for the UK, and on our server @@DateFirst **returns 7**

Comment: After further consideration there's still an issue with this. I'm going to refactor a bit and update.

Comment: Updated with a much more reliable approach.

Comment: @JC. thanks for your help - so in my column I just do `case when [date]>=@DeletablePeriodStart then 0 else 1` to show a record can be deleted as it's more than 3 working days old?

Comment: Yeah. There's no need to do complicated SQL acrobatics in your select. Really you just need to identify that start date and use it. (Though it looks like you have your 0 and 1 reversed)

Answer (score 1):

You should substract the number of holidays between a.[date] and GETDATE() from the DATEDIFF. Try something like this:

```
case when DATEDIFF(d,a.[date],GETDATE())-(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Holidays 
    WHERE HolidayDate BETWEEN a.[date] AND GETDATE()
)>3 then 1 else 0 end as [deletable]
```

Razvan

Comment: nice but I also need it to exclude weekends from the count, thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you don't have a [Calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), although I'd highly recommend creating one, you can still achieve this without one:

The following will just get you a list of 2047 dates from yesterday going backwards (using the system table `Master..spt_values`):

```
WITH Dates AS
(   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    FROM    Master..spt_values
    WHERE   type = 'P'
    AND     number > 0
)
SELECT  Dates.Date
FROM    Dates
ORDER BY Dates.Date DESC;
```

You then need to exclude weekends, and holidays from your table using this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

WITH Dates AS
(   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    FROM    Master..spt_values
    WHERE   type = 'P'
    AND     number > 0
)
SELECT  Dates.Date
FROM    Dates
WHERE   DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dates.Date) <= 5
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    HolidayTable h
            WHERE   Dates.Date = h.HolidayDate
        )
ORDER BY Dates.Date DESC;
```

*N.B. You should explicitly set your `DATEFIRST` and not rely on server defaults*

The above gives you a list of working days prior to today, you can then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, get the 3rd occurance in the list, giving a final query:

```
WITH Dates AS
(   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
    FROM    Master..spt_values
    WHERE   type = 'P'
    AND     number > 0
), WorkingDays AS
(   SELECT  Dates.Date, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Dates.Date DESC)
    FROM    Dates
    WHERE   DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dates.Date) <= 5
    AND     NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    HolidayTable h
                WHERE   Dates.Date = h.HolidayDate
            )
)
SELECT  WorkingDays.Date
FROM    WorkingDays
WHERE   RN = 3;
```

Or if you prefer this can be done with one query (exact same principle as above):

```
SELECT  d.Date
FROM    (   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, -number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number)
            FROM    Master..spt_values
            WHERE   type = 'P'
            AND     number > 0
            AND     DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, -number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) <= 5
            AND     NOT EXISTS
                    (   SELECT  1
                        FROM    HolidayTable h
                        WHERE   DATEADD(DAY, -number, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) = h.HolidayDate
                    )
        ) d
WHERE   rn = 3;
```

Comment: Warning: `Master..spt_values` is an undocumented table, and could very well be removed from future versions of SQL Server.

Comment: @TT. It is "undocumented", and as such *could* be removed from future versions, however, as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4280038/1048425), it is used internally by SQL-Server, so they are not required to document it, but given it is used internally (e.g. `SP_LOCK`), I would not be overly worried about its removal. Writing future proof code has it's merits, but should not be the be all and end all of it. If it is a massive concern use `SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM sys.all_objects` to generate a sequential list on the fly.

Comment: @GarethD +1 thanks, we have a Holidays table...and I tested your last code block by replacing `GETDATE()` with **'2013-05-28'** and it correctly returned '2013-05-22' which is nice...