# Rows in table with specific sum of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table containing some payments looking something like this:

```
id  |  from  |  to  |  amount
--------------------------
1   |   125  | 135  |  2.4
2   |   123  | 134  |  1.7
3   |   124  | 138  |  4.8
4   |   118  | 119  |  3.9
5   |   56   | 254  |  23.5
...
```

I need to know if there is a way to make SQL query that would tell me if there is a series of consecutive rows, the amount of which sums up to a certain value. For example, if I wanted value 6.5, it would return rows 2 to 3. If I wanted 12.8, it would return rows 1 to 4 and so on.

I am absolutely stuck and would appreciate some help.

Comment: you need to have a loop to check the sum with desired output and then output the rows

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Just a general point - for a large enough table that could be an extremely long running query, ensure at the very least that you remove any "amount" larger than the value you're searching for.

Comment: The problem is, there can be negative values too :-/

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this as follows.  First, calculate the cumulative sum.  Then, the condition that consecutive rows have a particular sum is equivalent to saying that the difference between two of the cumulative sums equals that value.

```
with p as (
      select p.*, sum(amount) over (order by id) as cumamount
      from payments p
     )
select 
from p p1 join
     p p2
     on p1.id <= p2.id and
       ( p2.cumamount - p1.cumamount ) = 6.5;
```

As a note:  this will probably not work if `amount` is stored as a floating point number because of very small inaccuracies.  If `amount` where an integer, it would be fine, but it clearly is not.  A fixed point representation should be ok.

Comment: I think you need to add a 0 row at the start for this method to work when the set starts at the first row? (although I don't have 2012 to hand, so I may have misinterpreted)

Comment: @podiluska . . . No.  But if the set could consist of just one row, then the `<` needs to be a `<=`.  I just made that change, despite the fact that the question seems to emphasize rows in the plural.

Comment: For those who've never heard of it before: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

Answer (score 2):

```
;with numbers as (select number from master..spt_values where type='p' and number between 1 and (Select MAX(id) from yourtable)),
ranges as ( select n1.number as start, n2.number as finish from numbers n1 cross join numbers n2 where n1.number<=n2.number)
    select yourtable.* from yourtable
        inner join
        (
            select start, finish
            from ranges
                inner join yourtable on id between start and finish
            group by start, finish
            having SUM(amount)=12.8 
        ) results
    on yourtable.id between start and finish
```

Comment: Be careful with that `spt_values` table, it seems to be an undocumented feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273723/what-is-the-purpose-of-system-table-table-master-spt-values-and-what-are-the-me

Comment: It's been there forever, and it likely always will be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273978/why-and-how-to-split-column-using-master-spt-values/4280038#4280038

Comment: The more important issue with `spt_values` is that the question doesn't limit the number of rows to 2,047.