# SQL: Convert table with start-end dates to just dates retaining other columns

Tags: sql, date

I understand that a number of similar questions have been answered, but I think none seems to be specific to this? I might be wrong as I am still quite new to SQL too. Hence, appreciate if anyone can kindly explain and point me the right direction.

A sample table is as shown below, with start and end dates, and one more column with some text details. Some of the end dates are NULL.

```
Start Date  End Date    Day
25-05-15    28-05-15    text1
28-05-15                text2
30-05-15                text3
01-12-15                text4
31-05-16    02-06-16    text5
07-07-16                text6
```

I want to convert this table to a new one just showing all the days while retaining the "Day" column specific to the dates.

```
Date        Day
25-05-15    text1
26-05-15    text1
27-05-15    text1
28-05-15    text1
28-05-15    text2
30-05-15    text3
01-12-15    text4
31-05-16    text5
01-06-16    text5
02-06-16    text5
07-07-16    text6
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should store date values as `DATE` data type.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi, I'm using vertica

Comment: Hi, the date values are in date time format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a helper table with all dates you would ever need (e.g. 30K dates from 1970-01-01), you can join it with your table on the given date range. This query is for MySQL:

```sql
select d.`Date`, t.`Day`
from mytable t
join `dates` d
  on  d.`Date` >= str_to_date(t.`Start Date`, '%d-%m-%y')
  and d.`Date` <= str_to_date(coalesce(`End Date`, `Start Date`), '%d-%m-%y')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e3e1/1

You can create that helper table on the fly or store it in your db for later use. How to create that table depends on your RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this within a script (this one is Oracle):

```
DECLARE

  CURSOR dt_cursor IS
    SELECT StartDate               AS FromDate,
           NVL(EndDate, StartDate) AS ToDate,
           Day
    FROM   myTable;

  dt_val  dt_cursor%ROWTYPE;
  my_date DATE;

BEGIN

  FOR dt_val IN dt_cursor LOOP

    my_date = dt_val.FromDate;
    WHILE (my_date <= dt_val.ToDate) LOOP

      INSERT INTO newTable (Date, Day) VALUES (my_date, dt_val.Day);
      my_date := my_date + 1;

    END LOOP;

  END LOOP;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below script for SQL server.

```
DROP TABLE #T
GO

CREATE TABLE #T
(StartDAte DATETIME,
 EndDate DATETIME,
 Day VARCHAR(50))


 INSERT INTO #T
 VALUES ('05-25-15','05-28-15','text1'), ('05-28-15',NULL,'text2')
        ,('05-30-15',NULL,'text3'),('12-01-15',NULL,'text4')
        ,('05-31-16','06-02-16','text5'),('07-07-16',NULL,'text6')
```

Below script will give you the result set.

```
 SELECT [Date],[Day] 
 FROM #T
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number,StartDAte) [Date]
                FROM master..spt_values
                WHERE type = 'P'
                AND DATEADD(DAY,number,StartDAte) < =ISNULL(EndDate,StartDate))t
```

Comment: Hi, I have trouble understanding the statement in the cross apply~ which table is "master..spt_values"? Where does the field "type" come from? Thanks!

Comment: jake, spt_values is a default system function available in sql server for manipulating the  strings.. Type P is a list of consecutive numbers between 0 and 2047.if you wantded to know more just follow the link.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273978/why-and-how-to-split-column-using-master-spt-values)