# SQL limiting Count function based on IN clause using comma delimited list

Tags: sql

I have a table of Matricies (JobMatricies) ID, Desc, DeptIDs

```
1   Admin (PM)  6,7,138,131,11,9,10,134,135,14,105,129
5   Sales Processing (PM)   92,16,153,17,91,32,26,93,99,18,89,90,155,19
6   Construction Processing (PM)    100,36,20,136,22,88,23,25,34,106,38,39,132,41,42,43,154,152,84
```

DeptIDs are a Comma Delimited list of departments that I want to use to count how many records are represented by the Matrix.

Normally I would do something like....

```
select  Matrix_ID, 
        Matrix_Desc, 
        JobCount =  (select count(sched_ID) from JobSchedule where dept_ID in                                                    (**92,16,153,17,91,32,26,93,99,18,89,90,155,19**))
from    jobMatrices
```

How do I replace the hard coded delimited string with the ID's stored with each matrix, so that I can produce a list of matricies with their own unique count based on the comma delimited string that is stored with each matrix.

Thanks

Comment: Fix your data model to be a proper relational model, where you do not store multiple numeric ids in a single string column.  I'm sure that will simplify most queries you want to write, including this one.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, appreciate the comments.  Yes, we can add another table to store each ID as a separate record then use a sub select.  Is there a way to solve the issue with how the data is currently stored?

Comment: What is your RDBMs ? Different flavors has different ways to handle comma separated values.

Comment: In Postgres you can use `cardinality(string_to_array(deptids,','))`

Comment: You will probably find an implementation of a `split` function appropriate for your database if you search for that.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question where the poster wanted to sum the delimited list of numbers in a similar table layout.  My solution used CTE's in Oracle to turn that list into a CTE table which would allow you to join against it.  I believe that technique would be of use here if your RDBMS supports that.  Please have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38231838/2543416

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.ID
     , m."Desc"
  from JobSchedule s
     , jobMatrices m
 where position(',' || s.ID || ',' in ',' || m.DeptIDs || ',')>0;

select m."Desc"
     , count(s.ID) JobCount
  from JobSchedule s
     , jobMatrices m
 where position(',' || s.ID || ',' in ',' || m.DeptIDs || ',')>0
 group by m."Desc";
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO, next time take your time to Format your codes in your future answers. Just adding a blank line before the text and four white spaces before every line of code.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can treat a comma-separated string as a SET, and there's a builtin function [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) that helps:

```
select  m.Matrix_ID, 
        m.Matrix_Desc, 
        (select count(sched_ID) from JobSchedule 
         where FIND_IN_SET(dept_ID, m.DeptIds)) AS JobCount
from    jobMatrices AS m;
```

This will have *terrible* performance, however.

If you use some RDBMS other than MySQL, they may have a different solution that works similarly.

You should be specific in your question and tag your question appropriately. You only tagged your question [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), but this is a *language* used by many RDBMS vendors.