# How to update a table with list of values in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I want to update one-to-many relationship records. The table def is:

```
CREATE TABLE CT_ProductFailures 
( 
PFID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
Old_Modes varchar(75), 
New_Modes varchar(75) 
)
```

Now I want to add records for New_Mode 'N1' with Old_Modes 'A', 'B', 'C'. 
Other than by doing separate insert statements, how can I achieve this?

Comment: No, I'd rather just use one insert statement.  I have a list of 1000 records and rather than manually type all these records before loading, I'm looking for a more automated solution.

Comment: Please provide an example of how your source data is currently formatted.

Comment: Above, I described in general terms how it is formatted.  It is one contiguous list: "A, B, C, D, ..." which is separated by comma delimiters between each record.  So I want to do as little manual work as possible.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 you can do this rather easily using syntax like below

```
INSERT INTO CT_ProductFaiures (Old_Modes, New_Modes)
VALUES ('N1', 'A'), ('N1', 'B'), ('N1', 'C');
```

This assumes PFID is auto incrementing.

You can use UNIONS do sort of achieve this in older versions. Check out the link below for great examples.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/07/02/sql-server-2008-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-row-constructor/

Comment: Yes, I have 2008 and yes, PFID is auto incrementing.  But I don't want to do it ur way cause then I have to type in each record.  Instead I want to copy this list so that all I have to do is add single quotes around each record.  And then I want to insert this list, so that each word gets added to a separate record.  Make sense?  (This list is already typed for me.)

Comment: If the list in in MS Excel, wouldn't it be easy to write a function in MS Excel to produce the VALUES format? For instance..."('"&A1&"', '"&B1&"'),"

Comment: ... or do a simple search and replace, or execute a macro in your favorite editor...

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO CT_ProductFailures (New_Modes, Old_Modes)
SELECT n.New_Modes, o.Old_Modes
FROM (SELECT 'N1' New_Modes) n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'A' Old_Modes
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'C') o
```

Alternatively, write a [split function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250475/split-one-column-into-multiple-rows#answer-4250686) using newline as the separator:

```
INSERT INTO CT_ProductFailures (New_Modes, Old_Modes)
SELECT 'N1' New_Modes, o.value Old_Modes
FROM dbo.split(
'A
B
C') o
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do this so that I can enter the list with one contiguous flow?  Like a way so that I don't need to add the extra "UNION ALL SELECT" between each record?  So all I have to do is add single quotes around each record?

Comment: Considered using BCP or BULK INSERT or SSMS Import or Excel Export.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan,

You are saying: 'Instead I want to copy this list so that all I have to do is add single quotes around each record'.
It is not clear how your list is formated.

Let's assume you have the list like this (comma separated values)

```
N1, A
N1, B
N1, C
```

What you can do is:

1. Copy/paste the list to SQL Server Management Studio
2. Run some replacements using regular expressions:

   - hit Ctrl+H to open 'Find and Replace' dialog
   - in Find Options select Use 'Regular expressions'
   - Find what: [^] Replace with: [('] Hit 'Replace All'
     **Don't type square parenthesis in. I used them to make sure you could see the spaces!**
   - Find what: [$] Replace with: ['),] Hit 'Replace All'
   - Find what: [, ] Replace with: [', '] Hit 'Replace All'
   - Remove the last redundant comma

   You will end up with the list like this:

   ```
   ('N1', 'A'),
   ('N1', 'B'),
   ('N1', 'C')
   ```
3. Then add insert statement at the top of the script :

   ```
   insert into CT_ProductFaiures (Old_Modes, New_Modes)
   values
   ```

So in the result you have this

```
insert into CT_ProductFaiures (Old_Modes, New_Modes)
values 
('N1', 'A'),
('N1', 'B'),
('N1', 'C')
```

Hope that this is what you needed.

[Edited]
I'm sorry, didn't pay attention.
So list is formatted like this: A, B, C, D.
Then you just replace [,] with ['), ('N1', '] without any regular expressions.
Also, fix starting and ending value manually.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I would have responded earlier but my SSMS program at home crashed and wouldn't start.  Thank you for your helps!  However, can u try running that insert with multi-values in one pass?  I get an error if I try to insert more than one record at a time

Comment: What kind of error do you see? Does the table have a trigger on insert?

Comment: @Ryan - You didn't like any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table called NewTable with the A B C records with another New_Modes field.

Use this table in your insert command.